# Export To Excel a gridcontrol from devexpress with autosize of columns

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using a grid control from devexpress.I export the informations to excel using this code :

```
grdExport.ExportToXls('C:\Test.xls');
```

But when I export data to excel or pdf all the columns has width of 1 cm.How can I export to excel/pdf and make autosize to columns or keep the width columns from the grid?(in grid the columns has autosize and looks fine).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to call `grdExport.BestFitColumns` [Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BestFitColumnstopic)
and set  `grdExport.OptionsPrint.AutoWidth` property to `false`.

Check this [Question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q294264)